# To what does the word “il” refer in “un grand sac qu'il mit sur son dos”?

Tags: pronoms-relatifs, pronoms-personnels

I have this sentence :

> En un clin d’œil, le loup les attrapa et les jeta dans un grand sac
>   qu'**il** mit sur son dos.

I would tend to say that the bold **il** word refers to **le sac**. But if I replace **le loup** by **la louve**, then I would write the sentence this way :

> En un clin d’œil, la louve les attrapa et les jeta dans un grand sac
>   qu'**elle** mit sur son dos.

So I'm quite confused about this situation. What's your opinion ?

Comment: Have you not answered your own question?

Comment: Maybe yes. But as a native speaker, this is a paradox feeling I had, and I wanted to have other opinions to understand what was wrong about my feeling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *il* replaces *le loup*.

There is indeed a reference to *le sac* as well, which is the word *qu'*, having a direct object function. You can learn more about relative pronouns [here](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/relative-pronouns/) for example.

If you want to make sure your instinct is right, you could change the word *sac* by a feminine word:

> En un clin d’œil, le loup les attrapa et les jeta dans une grande caisse qu'**il** mit sur son dos.

Comment: That's a nice contre example ! I guess my initial feeling is wrong, and I was confused by the proximity of qu' and il.

Comment: @Akah That would be an instinct to question! It's hard to imagine a situation like « le <GN> qu'il <GV> » where « que » and « il » could refer to the same entity.